# Load scene using canvas button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("Scene2");
}
```

I have tried every conceivable method. The method posted has worked for me using GameObjects with colliders. Instead, this time I am using a button on a 2D canvas. It does not work in this context.

How do I load a new scene using a button in a canvas? I have tried so many different things. This should be simple.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here (link: [Unity page](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-button)) you can find a video tutorial how to use Button on canvas in UnityGUI. It's for Unity 4.6 but its really simillar to newest (5.3.1).

It's quite simple. U can make a script with public method e.g

```
public void LoadScene2()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("Scene2");
}
```

Attach this script to some GameObject e.g Controller. And add event in Button inspector.

Comment: The solution was definitely not obvious but this video did explain it. I used your code, attached the script to a gameobject (main camera) and then connected that gameobject to the button in the inspector. From there I was able to select the function LoadScene2(). Thanks for the help that was spot on.

Comment: I sugest you read my response, although this answer is 100% correct, its not optimal if your scene name changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is a better solution for the one shown by @Paweł Marecki
I use this in my projects.
OK so you will simply create a script called `ButtonManager` and inside it you can make a method like this

```
public void ChangeToScene(string sceneName)
{
  Application.LoadLevel(sceneName);
  OR
  SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
}
```

Now you have your canvas button, you will select it and look for "Event Trigger"
(i got this image from google to help) add a new mouse down event.
Create an empty GameObject on your Scene, name it "ButtonManager" and drag it onto the event box.

Now you need to click that dropDown list and find your "ChangeToScene" method.
You will see that an editor field appears below, type your desired scene name and hit play :P

This way you will always use this script when you want to change scenes.
You can add other methods and add functionality, but the beautiful part is that you dont need to create a method each time the name of the scene changes.

[image]

Comment: Note that Application.Loadlevel has been deprecated since 5.5.